# jQuery flowplayer tooltip: show/hide events not being called in correct order

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, jquery-tools, flowplayer

I am using jquery tools Tooltip to create tooltips.

I created a tooltip like this...a tooltip which only opens on clicking and closes when I press a close button(triggering "closeTooltip" event).

```
$('#request_button').tooltip({
        opacity: 1.0,
        position: 'top center',
        offset: [10, 0],
        events: {
            def: "openTooltip, closeTooltip",
            tooltip: "undefinedEvent, closeTooltip"
        },
        onBeforeShow: function() {
            alert("I will hide the existing tooltips first");
            $('#request_button').trigger('closeTooltip');
        },
        onShow: function() {
            alert("I have shown the new tooltip");
        },
        onBeforeHide: function() {
            alert("I have started hiding existing tooltips");
        },
        onHide: function() {
            alert("I have hidden all existing tooltips");
        },
        tip: "#tooltip_contents" // I am using same div for multiple trigger elements
    });
```

I am opening/closing the tooltip like this..

```
$('#request_button').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('openTooltip');
});
$('#close_tooltip').click(function() {
    $('#request_button).trigger('closeTooltip');
});
```

Since I have multiple trigger elements defined I have the necessity to close any open tooltips. When I tried this in onBeforeShow() event, it didn't work out the way I wanted.

The alert messages appeared in the following order...

- I will hide the existing tooltips first
- I have shown the new tooltip
- I have started hiding existing tooltips
- I have hidden all existing tooltips

What this does is it hides the current tooltip as well.
The order I want is...

- I will hide the existing tooltips first
- I have started hiding existing tooltips
- I have hidden all existing tooltips
- I have shown the new tooltip

How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me was the following code...

```
$("#request_button").click(function (e)
{
    var tooltip_api = $(this).data('tooltip');
    if (tooltip_api.isShown(true)) {
        tooltip_api.hide();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Did a similar thing today I think. I'm using the events: to set the click stuff so no need to write a click function for the trigger.

`onBeforeShow` just hides all div's that would be tooltips.

Also appended in the tooltip with a close link.

```
$(".will-be-hidden").tooltip({
  onBeforeShow: function() { $('.unique-id').hide(); },
  events: { def: 'click, mouseout', tooltip: 'mouseover, click'},
  effect: 'slide',
  position: "center right",
  opacity: 0.7,
  relative: true,
  offset: [-20,-100],
  opacity: 1.0
}).dynamic({ right: { direction: 'left' } });

$('div.unique-id').append('<br /><br /><p style="cursor:pointer; color:#003B81">x click to close</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well at the moment it's showing before it's hiding. Calling onBeforeShow, onShow, onBeforeHide, onHide. My assumption is that this is the way that the tooltip plugin runs. The order you say you want is onBeforeShow, onBeforeHide, onHide, onShow which is pretty nonsensical.

What I imagine you want to do is fairly simply hide all tooltips before showing the current one in which case, can't you do that in the events that trigger the tooltip? Something like:

```
$("#request_button").click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault;
    $(".reference_to_tooltip_here").trigger("closeTooltip"); // or just .remove()/.hide();
    $(this).trigger("openTooltip");
});
```

That way all tooltips are closed before a new tooltip is opened? If there aren't any options to hide other tooltips in your plugins functionality, ignore the events it comes with and have jQuery close them before opening.

Also just fyi, you **currently** have:

```
    onBeforeShow: function() {
    alert("I will hide the existing tooltips first");
    $('#request_button').trigger('closeTooltipEvent');
```

which I think needs to be `trigger('closeTooltip');` anyway.